# ODBC connection from Clickhouse to MSSQL databases

Tags: sql-server, odbc, clickhouse

Please help with ODBC connection from Clickhouse to SQL Server databases.
I configured **ODBC** on the Clickhouse server. 
Сonnection from clients such as **isql**, **tsql** is successful.
But it is not possible to connect from the clickhouse client's.

```
Operation system – Ubuntu 20.04
Clickhouse Server – version 22.1.3
Clickhouse Client – version 18.16.1 
MS SQL Server 2016 on Windows Server.
```

1. /etc/freetds/freetds.conf

```
    [TSQL_NE]
    host = 10.72.82.72
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.4
    client charset = UTF-8
```

2. /etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
FileUsage=1
UsageCount=8
```

3. /etc/odbc.ini

```
[TSQL_NE]
Description=FreeTDS NE
Driver=FreeTDS
Server=10.72.82.72
Database=ASU
UID=user
PWD=password
Port=1433
```

4. Checking the connection to the MSSQL database via ODBC

```
root@srv:/# isql -v TSQL_NE "user" "password"

    +---------------------------------------+
    | Connected! |
    | |
    | sql-statement |
    | help [tablename] |
    | quit |
    | |
    +---------------------------------------+

SQL> SELECT top 10 v1 from asu.dbo.data

    +-------------------------+
    | V1                      |
    +-------------------------+
    | 1.45                    |
    | 1.5062500000000001      |
    | 1.385                   |
    | 1.4237500000000001      |
    | 1.3712500000000001      |
    | 1.425                   |
    | 1.39625                 |
    | 1.6487499999999999      |
    | 1.28                    |
    | 1.2037500000000001      |
    +-------------------------+
    SQLRowCount returns 10
    10 rows fetched
```

```
root@srv:/# tsql -v -S TSQL_NE -U user –P password

    locale is "C.UTF-8"
    locale charset is "UTF-8"
    using default charset "UTF-8"
    1> SELECT top 10 v1 from asu.dbo.data
    …
    10 rows fetched
```

5. Connection with clickhouse-client and the error

```
root@srv:~# clickhouse-client

    ClickHouse client version 18.16.1.
    Password for user :
    Connecting to localhost:9000.
    Connected to ClickHouse server version 22.2.2 revision 54455.

b7e1d742cbd0 :) SELECT top 10 v1 from odbc('DSN=TSQL_NE;Uid=user;Pwd=password;', 'asu', 'dbo.data')

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.290 sec.

Received exception from server (version 22.2.2):

> Code: 86. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000, 127.0.0.1. 
DB::Exception: Received error from remote server /columns_info?connection_string=DSN%3DTSQL_NE%3B%20Uid%3Duser%3BPwd%3Dpassword%3B&table=dbo.data&external_table_functions_use_nulls=true. 
HTTP status code: 500 Internal Server Error, body: Error getting columns from ODBC 
'Code: 36. DB::Exception: Table dbo.data not found. (BAD_ARGUMENTS) (version 22.2.2.1)'
```

Comment: It looks like it needs to ignore _dbo_-schema in query: ```SELECT top 10 v1 FROM odbc('DSN=TSQL_NE;Uid=user;Pwd=password;', 'asu', 'data')```

Comment: ASU – Database, dbo – schema, data- table
`select v1 from odbc('DSN=TSQL_NE; Uid=user;Pwd=password;', 'asu’, ‘data')`
 Code: 86. DB::....3B& **schema=asu** & **table=data** &external_table_functions_use_nulls=true.      HTTP status code: 500 Internal Server Error, body: Error getting columns from ODBC 'std::exception. Code: 1001, type: nanodbc::database_error, e.what() = ../contrib/nanodbc/nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:4925: 2400: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid cursor state'

Comment: `select V1 from odbc('DSN=TSQL_NE; Uid=user; Pwd=password;', 'asu.dbo.data')`

Received exception from server (version 22.2.2):
Code: 86. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000, 127.0.0.1. DB::Exception: Received error from remote server /columns_info?connection_string=DSN%3DTSQL_NE%3B%20Uid%3Duser%3BPwd%3Dpassword%3B& **table=asu.dbo.data** &external_table_functions_use_nulls=true. HTTP status code: 500 Internal Server Error, body: Error getting columns from ODBC 'Code: 36. DB::Exception: Table **asu.dbo.data** not found. (BAD_ARGUMENTS) (version 22.2.2.1)'

Comment: did you try use official ODBC instead of FreeTDS ? https://gist.github.com/9f9449a722091a13a9069b79f8dc7da7

Comment: @Slach Yes, i tried official ODBC, but unsuccessfully.
odbcinst.ini 
`[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]`
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.0.so.1.1`   
odbc.ini
`[MSSQL_NE]
Driver=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Server=tcp:10.72.82.72,1433`

root@srv:/# isql -v MSSQL_NE "user" "password"
[08001][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746
[08001][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

Answer (score 0):

You command in clickhouse-client should be

```
SELECT top 10 v1 from odbc('DSN=TSQL_NE;Uid=user;Pwd=password;Database=asu', 'dbo', 'data')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT top 10 v1 from odbc('DSN=TSQL_NE;Uid=user;Pwd=password;', '', 'data')
```

When you remove schema and database you will get success. I saw this method in [here](https://hakanmazi123.medium.com/sql-server-to-clickhouse-with-odbc-driver-d484a117bfd0)